# PDF to html converter

Tags: php, pdf, html

i'm looking for php library to convert pdf to html,The goal is to not lose structure and styles.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! What did you [research](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) until now?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782751/convert-pdf-to-html-in-php